# Jersey Custom Exception Message

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, tomcat7

I've written a Jersey Server application and a Client application which is consuming the provided REST Services.
But I've problems to pass exception messages from server to client.
Currently I've implemented it like:

Server WS Method:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public TestModel doTest(){
    throw new NotImplementedException("[doTest] is not implemented yet");
}
```

NotImplementedException:

```
public class NotImplementedException extends WebApplicationException{
        public NotImplementedException(){
             super(Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
                     .entity("The operation you've called is not implemented yet").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
        }

        public NotImplementedException(String message){
             super(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_GATEWAY).entity(message).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public static TestModel doTest() throws Exception{
        try {
            Client client = getClient();

            WebTarget webTarget = client.target("server..../");
            WebTarget getGuTarget = webTarget.path("test");

            Invocation.Builder ib = getGuTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


            TestModel response = ib.get(TestModel.class); //here exception is thorwn
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The exception caught on the Client looks like:

```
javax.ws.rs.ServerErrorException: HTTP 502 Bad Gateway
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.createExceptionForFamily(JerseyInvocation.java:1029)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1009)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:799)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:91)
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to receive the "[doTest] is not implemented yet" Message on the client. How I can get this message?

When I test the webservice I receive the correct message in the body. Unfortunately I don't know how I can access it via jersey?

Thanks.

Comment: I expect to have access to the message. But even if I set the Status to "600" I do not have access to the message. It is sent in the body (verified with rest client) but is not mapped to any attribute/object within jersey

Comment: Get the `Response` by calling `get` with no argument, then `response.read Entity(String.class)` to get the string response message. See what happens

Comment: Uhh good point. Only disadvantage is that I've to map now the response to the correct object, depending on the status code - but it is working.

Comment: Not really much to it. Really only one conditional is required. If status is 200 do normal, or else read string and show error :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an ExceptionMapper for custom exceptions: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html

Otherwise, Jersey tries to map exceptions as good as it can on its own.

Comment: ExceptionMapper only catches non WebAppExceptions. If I just throw a new Exception on server side (`new Exception('test')`) instead of `NotImplementedException` I still not receive the exception message on client. `toResponse` Method: `return Response.status(600).entity(e.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();`